# How to get 'java.io.IOException No space left on device' using ZipFileSystem

Tags: java, java-8, nio2

I save several files in a zip file using Java's FileSystem. If there is not enough disk space I can not get `java.io.IOException No space left on device` and it behaves as if the zip file were created successfully.

Here is a snippet from my project:

```
Path pathToZip = Paths.get("path/to/existing/zip");

try(FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(pathToZip, null)) {
    // zip some files via
    Path pathToSomeFile = Paths.get("path/of/some/file/to/be/zipped");
    Files.copy(pathToSomeFile, fs.getPath("/path/of/some/file/to/be/zipped"));
} catch (IOException ex) {
    log.error("error on zipping files", ex);
}
```

The `FileSystems.newFileSystem(pathToZip, null)` creates a `ZipFileSystem` instance. I've debugged up to the method `sync()` of the class `ZipFileSystem`. Then, when the `java.io.IOException No space left on device` occurs, only `x.printStackTrace()` is called and the exception is gone.

What options do I have to see if the file was successfully written?

Comment: File a bug report. Catching such exceptions and proceeding with corrupted data definitely is a bug.

Comment: Thanks. I have just created a bug report. Once it has passed the review process, I will post the link here.

Comment: The assigned Bug ID is JDK-8225507. The issue is visible at the following url [JDK-8225507](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8225507).